# How to cover seams on a board & batten interior wall when calculations won't add up?

Tags: trim-carpentry

We want to put board and batten on a feature wall in the living room.  We plan to cover the textured wall with some type of 4'x 8' board.  After doing multiple calculations we couldn't make the battens cover all the vertical seams without spacing the battens unevenly (not a look we want).  What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide a sketch and indicate the layout problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rip down the 4 x 8 sheets into a width that will cover the length without a noticeable difference in batten spacing. 16 inch width works well with no waste on a sheet. While the finished look is a matter of preference, the smaller sections do have good look and disguise minor differences in panel sizes. MDF is my go to for the panels if you are painting the wall.